# Backup Image for <video> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have extensively read and tried every solution in other threads with no luck.

**My issue is this: when a browser does not support video tag, the backup image that I have set up does not show, and the video-div shows nothing but the background of body.**

Here is the code I am using for the video/image:

```
            <div id="video-div">
              <video id="landing-video" autoplay loop>
              <source src="images/landing-video.m4v" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
              <source src="images/landing-video-webm.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
              <img src="images/landing-video-backup.JPG" title="Your broswer does not support the <video> tag"/>
            </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

**poster**

> A URL indicating a poster frame to show until the user plays or
>   seeks. If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until
>   the first frame is available; then the first frame is shown as the
>   poster frame.

---

You need to use poster attribute not an image tag.

```
<video id="landing-video" poster="images/landing-video-backup.JPG" autoplay loop>
  <source src="images/landing-video.m4v" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="images/landing-video-webm.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Works perfectly now!